Repository pattern for external API? Or excel file?
In web applications it is common practice to use repository pattern for data access. Usually this is the way to extract data from a database. For example:
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base(...)

class User(Base):
    id: ...
    first_name: ...
    last_name: ...


class UserRepository(BaseRepository):
    def get_by_id(self, ...): pass
    def get_all(self, ...): pass
    # etc

But what if the source of data are external API or excel file? When working with API they usually call a repository as a "client". But it gets data and the meaning is the same. Should I name the class SomeExternalAPIRepository? What about extracting data from Excel file? SomeExcelRepository?
What is naming convention for listed cases?

STANDARDIZATION EFFORTS
I wasn't aware of this but @mrSoh pointed me to an excellent resource called The Standard in his comment below, where the term broker is used.
MY ORIGINAL ANSWER
This is how I reason about it. When I make a client connection I tend to use the word client, which I find descriptive:

OrdersApiClient
CustomersApiClient
OAuthClient

When I am dealing with files or databases I tend to use the term repository and name the item after a business area, though in some cases a term like OrdersDbClient would work just as well:

OrdersRepository
CustomersRepository

Even though databases involve a client connection, sometimes you consult different types of data source for the same business area. Or you perform joins that span business areas. When that might be the case I prefer the term repository.
My goal is always that my views and view models (most of my code) are business focused, eg based on order and customer objects. All of the plumbing, such as connection retries or error translation, are handled by the client / repository class.
SUMMARY
There is more than one way of achieving these goals, so go with your own preferences. Always aim for these qualities:

Use separation of concerns
Keep the business logic readable, including its error handling
Use technology neutral patterns
Use naming that scales, eg when you have many repositories


A theory has been around and evolving that covers such naming conventions and many other aspects of design patterns, called The Standard. It basically mentions that external communications (whether with APIs, external dependencies, etc..) can be called Brokers eg. ApiBroker or StorageBroker etc...

Interesting - hadn't seen that. Good to see a focus on writing code in a technology neutral way based on solid principles. I will add your point to my answer
